# ScrollViewer from a ListView is not recognized in a trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

in a text block I set a trigger to control the width of the text block. In the trigger I want to query whether the vertical scrollbar of the ListView ListViewA visible is.
But the binding does not work. Neither 'ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility' nor 'VerticalScrollBarVisibility' is accepted: "Can not resolve property" ScrollViewer "(or" VerticalScrollBarVisibility ") in dataContext of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Listview'.
What should I change?

Alexander

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <Setter Property="Width" Value="453" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <!--Binding-Error!-->
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility, ElementName=ListViewA}" Value="Visible">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>

<ListView x:Name="ListViewA" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

Comment: `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` is an attached property, it requieres `()` in binding path: `"{Binding (ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility), ElementName=ListViewA}"`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it atm, but it should work, but try this

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="453" />
    <Style.Triggers>
      <!--Binding-Error!-->
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility), ElementName=ListViewA}" Value="Visible">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" />
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This is because VerticalScrollBarVisibility is attached property rather than dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

Three problems here:

First, the `ScrollViewer.*` properties are attached properties. What you've got for a `Path` in your binding implies that `TextBlock` has a `ScrollViewer` property, which in turn has a `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property, but that's not what you're trying to express at all. `ScrollViewer.` is part of the attached property's name, rather than an additional property path element. You indicate that by putting `ClassName.PropertyName` in parens: `{Binding (ClassName.PropertyName)}`.

Secondly, `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` will be `Auto`, because that's what you set it to in an attribute. If you want the "live" runtime value, you need to use a different property -- just like `Width` vs `ActualWidth`. In this case, `ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility` is the one you want. It happens that that property doesn't work the way you'd think (that's Problem Three, below), but if it did, your XAML would look like this:

```
<DataTrigger 
    Binding="{Binding (ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility), ElementName=ListViewA}" 
    Value="Visible"
    >
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DeepSkyBlue" />
</DataTrigger>
```

`Computed`, `Actual`, tomato, potahto. Nobody said it had to make sense.

The final and worst problem is that the attached property `ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility` on the `ListView` is *meaningless garbage*. It always returns `Visible`. So you can't do this in straight XAML. We'll have to write a value converter that finds the actual `ScrollViewer` object within the ListView's visual tree, and returns one of its properties.

```
public class GetVisualDescendantProperty : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public DependencyProperty Property { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as DependencyObject)
            ?.GetDescendants()
            .Where(d => d.GetType() == Type)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            ?.GetValue(Property);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetDescendants(this DependencyObject obj)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); ++i)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            yield return child;
            foreach (var descendant in child.GetDescendants())
            {
                yield return descendant;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<DataTrigger 
    Binding="{Binding ElementName=ListViewA, Converter={local:GetVisualDescendantProperty Property=ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility, Type=ScrollViewer}}"
    Value="Visible"
    >
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="300" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DeepSkyBlue" />
</DataTrigger>
```

We don't need the parens around `Property=ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility` in the `MarkupExtension` initialization because this string isn't being parsed as a `PropertyPath`. Because the property is declared as `public DependencyProperty Property`, the XAML parser doesn't have to try to guess what it's looking at.